# Name of the following "fundamental construction" on fibration

Tags: ct.category-theory, fibration

The following "fundamental construction" is mentioned in Bart Jacobs's thesis, from which we can derive a few useful fibrations

[image]

I have some blind spot ironing everything out, and wanted to look up some other references about it.

Does this construction have a name ?

Comment: I don't know of a name for it that you'll be able to look up (I've never seen it anywhere but Jacobs' book), but if I had to call it something I'd probably call it a "fiberwise simple fibration", since on each fiber of E it is the usual simple fibration.

Comment: that's good to know and something to ponder. thank you !